# jQuery - Why it replaces the value twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to convert ":)" to smile image in the string. Used this;

```
var post = "hello :)";
post = post.replace(/[:)]/g, "<img src='smile.png' \>");
```

However, the output is

```
Hello <img src='smile.png' \> <img src='smile.png' \>
```

How can I prevent it being replacing incorrectly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is matching both `:` and `)` and replacing them one by one

Make it

```
post = post.replace(/(:\))/g, "<img src='smile.png' \/>");
```

Comment: But self closing img tag '/>' also replaced.

Comment: @SudharsanS no, the backslash just needs to be escaped itself, since it otherwise it tries to escapes the `>`.

Comment: Img tag is dom element it ends  with single slash not like double slashes coming in that

Comment: @SudharsanS yes, realized that after posting my comment. Fixed it now

Comment: I was wondering what was the problem and see the fix now :) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```js
var post = "hello :)";
post = post.replace(/(:\))/, "<img src='smile.png' \>");
console.log(post)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    var post = "hello :)";
    post = post.replace(/(:\))/g, "<img src='smile.png' \>");
```

Comment: Very slightly improved since it only does one replace, but has the same problem as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var post = "hello :)";

post = post.replace(
    /[:)]/g,
    "<img src='smile.png' \>"
).once();
```

Comment: Will it work if string contains "Hello :) how are you :) " ?

Comment: Erm, doesn't even work - `post.replace` will return a string already.

Comment: var s = "hello :) world :)"

var post = s.replace(":)", "your code here");

alert(post);

console.log(post);

this will replace only the first ":)"